# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x}$$

I know that it's $1$ using L'Hopital's rule or numerically, but what about algebraically? Thanks in advance and I really appreciate it.

Comment: What does "tan-1x" mean?? Maybe you wanted to write $\arctan (x)$ (?)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I fixed the bad typesetting.

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1) will definitely help.

Comment: Use the change of variable $x=\tan t$, knowing that the tangent function is continuous at the origin.

Answer (score 4):

With $y=\tan x$,
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\arctan x}{x}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\tan y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y\cos y}{\sin y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\cos y\cdot \lim_{y\to 0}\frac y{\sin y}=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac y{\sin y}=1$$

Comment: Caution, your change of variable is $x=\tan y$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the power series expansion of $\arctan$, $\arctan(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\ldots$, to get $\arctan(x)/x=1-\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{5}-\ldots$.

Comment: As usual, it is highly questionable that the power series isn't L'Hospital in disguise (i.e. using differentiation).

Comment: @YvesDaoust why can't the power series be found without using L'Hopital? Eg by using the binomial expansion of $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$ and integrating?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: integration is worse than differentiation ;-) But your suggestion about the generalized binomial is good.

Comment: @YvesDaoust :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the series expansion at $x = 0$

$$\dfrac{\arctan x}{x} = 1 - \dfrac{x^2}{3} + \dfrac{x^4}{5} + O(x^6)$$

Thus
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\arctan x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} {1 - \dfrac{x^2}{3} + \dfrac{x^4}{5} + O(x^6)} = 1 $$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\arctan x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\arctan x-\arctan 0}{x-0}=\dfrac{d\arctan(x)}{dx}(0)=\cos^2(\arctan 0)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use L'Hopital, or series expansion, then I suggest the following :

Notice that for any $ x\in\mathbb{R}^{*} $, we have : $$ \frac{\arctan{x}}{x}=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+x^{2}y^{2}}}=1-x^{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{y^{2}}{1+x^{2}y^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y} $$

Since, for all $ x\in\mathbb{R}^{*} $, $$ \left|x^{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{y^{2}}{1+x^{2}y^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right|\leq x^{2}\int_{0}^{1}{y^{2}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\frac{x^{2}}{3}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Then $ \lim\limits_{x\to 0}{x^{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{y^{2}}{1+x^{2}y^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y}}=0 $, which means : \begin{aligned} \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\arctan{x}}{x}}&=\lim_{x\to 0}{\left(1-x^{2}\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{y^{2}}{1+x^{2}y^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}y}\right)}\\ &=1-0\\ \lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\arctan{x}}{x}}&=1\end{aligned}